# Dynamically find Chrome on end-user's Windows machine

Tags: windows, google-chrome, environment-variables, file-shortcut

So, I have searched everywhere I can think of for this, and can't figure it out. I'm hoping the answer is very simple. Here is the situation:

I am creating a shortcut link for an end-user. We will call it "shortcut.lnk". We can assume that they do have Chrome installed and that "myFolder" is on their Desktop. The key is that this app needs to open up in Chrome, not the user's default browser. Currently, I have the following as the "Target" of shortcut.lnk:

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --app=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\myFolder\path\to\app.html
```

This works on the 3 machines I have tested it on. However, I have noticed from research that Chrome sometimes installs in AppData or other locations instead of Program Files.

My question is this, is there a way to dynamically determine where Chrome is installed on their Windows machine in a way that I can attach it to the "Target" of shortcut.lnk?

Comment: Are you able to use Powershell? if so see [Use PowerShell to Find Installed Software](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/11/15/use-powershell-to-find-installed-software.aspx). Won't work for finding my Portable Chrome though :)

Comment: Why you can't use IE? Or default browser(Win+R-> `http://superuser.com`). If you really want Chrome you should check registry for path to Chrome, but this not 100% solution.

Comment: @crazypotato Unfortunately, the app is just not sufficient to work in IE. These users have all from IE 6 to IE 11 but it seems to function in Chrome consistently. Can I check registry path using environment variables?

Comment: @DavidPostill I can't be confident that they have Powershell and in my first prototype, I had a "ClickMe.bat" file that was able to be more complex and that was canned. So, now I am constrained to things like environment variables in the Target of shortcut.lnk

Comment: Impossible use environment variable for find not standard path to Chrome. Only if someone already set path to some variable.

Comment: @crazypotato yeah, that makes sense. I was just hoping there was a way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Is there a way to dynamically determine where Chrome is installed?

The following command will determine where chrome is installed and set the `CHROMEPATH` environment variable to this value:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4,5" %a in (`reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ /s /f \chrome.exe ^| findstr Application`) do set CHROMEPATH=%c%d%e
```

Example output:

```
echo %CHROMEPATH%
C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

To use in a batch file you need to double up the percents as follows:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4,5" %%a in (`reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ /s /f \chrome.exe ^| findstr Application`) do set CHROMEPATH=%%c%%d%%e
```

Comment: This is fantastic! I love the idea of creating a new environment variable. Thanks!

Comment: does it need a modification to run from bat file?

Comment: @mike_x_ Yes. You need to double up the percents. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem, and since the script made by @DavidPostill didn't work on powershell, I made my own based on his answer.

```
function Find-PSFilePathInRegistry {
    param (
        [string]$FileName
    )
    $str = reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ /s /f \chrome.exe | findstr Default
    # regex to find the drive letter until $FileName
    if ($str -match "[A-Z]\:.+$FileName") {
        return @{
            success = $true
            path = $Matches[0]
        }
    }
    else {
        return @{
            success = $false
            path = ""
        }
    }
}
```

Use as following:

```
$res = Find-FilePathInRegistry "chrome.exe"
$res.success
True
$res.path
C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

If not found, `$res.success` will be `$false`.

Answer (score 0):

So I ran into needing this for locating applications in order to create new shortcuts on endpoints. This function saved me SO MUCH TIME as my need to find the chrome executable in an environment when Chrome is sometimes in two places has made my life so much easier! Thank you!
I did some tweaking to it and want to share back, so...

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
Searches the Windows registry for the path of a specified application file.

.DESCRIPTION
The Find-PSFilePathInRegistry function searches the Windows registry for the path of a specified application file. It allows you to locate the installation directory of an application by searching through the registry keys associated with installed software.

.PARAMETER FileName
Specifies the name of the application file to search for in the registry.

.OUTPUTS
Outputs a custom object with the following properties:
- Success: Indicates whether the search was successful (true/false).
- Path: The full path to the specified application file.
- AppDir: The directory where the application file is located.

.EXAMPLE
Find-PSFilePathInRegistry -FileName "chrome.exe"
Searches the Windows registry for the path of the Google Chrome executable file.

.EXAMPLE
Find-PSFilePathInRegistry -FileName "notepad.exe"
Searches the Windows registry for the path of the Notepad executable file.

.NOTES
The function searches the following registry keys:
- HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
- HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths
#>
function Find-PSFilePathInRegistry {
    param (
        [string]$FileName
    )

    # Define an array of common registry locations where application paths are stored
    $registryKeys = @(
        "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths",
        "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths"
    )

    # Iterate through each registry key
    foreach ($key in $registryKeys) {
        if (Test-Path $key) {
            # Get the default value (which usually contains the path) for the specified file name
            $value = Get-ItemProperty -Path "$key\$FileName" -Name "(default)" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            if ($value) {
                $appDir = Split-Path -Path $value.'(default)' -Parent
                return @{
                    Success = $true
                    Path = $value.'(default)'
                    AppDir = $appDir
                }
            }
        }
    }

    # If the path is not found in any of the registry keys, return failure
    return @{
        Success = $false
        Path = ""
        AppDir = ""
    }
}
```